# Questions on Data Quality Assessment

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, dataset, large-data, survey-sampling

I have been bumping my head against wall in trying to figure out a good real-world solution for this challenging problem that my friend asked me.

Could you please give some pointers?

Lets say we want to assess the data quality of Company A's big data. Due to both security, privacy and work-load concerns, it's impossible to view/access the whole data repository(data-lake or data-ocean) of A.

We can only request a sample of Company A's big data and then hopefully we can apply some quality-assess-toolkit to do some analysis.

My question is: how to draw such a data sample? what requirements should we set up for such a data sample?

Moreover, Company A may "optimize" or "decorate" the sample data that he gives out, what might be a good scheme or mechanism design such that we can avoid his "optimization" or "decoration"?

Could anybody please give some pointers?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The sample should be (a) as large as possible and (b) representative (if you are talking of a data lake, it should have samples for every table/ document).

You could further ask them to share descriptive statistics of their whole dataset beyond the sample (total count of rows per table / count of NaN values per column/table) - which should not be a problem of security / privacy.

Yet I am not sure whether it is possible to assess an abstract data quality. The question really is: What do they want to achieve? Secondly one can then ask whether the data is fit to answer this specific question.